# Attempting to assign variables to each other in a foreach loop based off the parameters in the loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, foreach, eloquent

I have two arrays which I have passed to my Laravel view. I want to run a loop that will set a State variable equal to the total variable. For some reason the variables are not being set, even though I have defined them before the loop. I know I have the right variables lined up, because when I do a simple echo of the two I get the right results.

Complete code posted:

map.blade.php

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stately.css">

@define $AK = ""
@define $AL = ""
@define $AR = ""
@define $AZ = ""
@define $CA = ""
....
@define $WY = ""
@define $arr = array_combine($allstates, $alltotals)

@foreach ($arr as $allstates => $alltotals)
  @define $array[$allstates] = $alltotals
  {{ $allstates }} {{ $alltotals }}<br>
  @define $allstates = $alltotals
  {{ $allstates }} {{ $alltotals }}<br>
@endforeach
</head>
<body>
  [Map here]
{{ $PA }}
</body>
```

Controller:

```
public function map()
{

    $allstates = DB::table('distributors')->lists('state');
    $alltotals = DB::table('distributors')->lists('total');

    $merged = DB::table('distributors')->lists('state','total');

    return View::make('map')
    ->with(compact('allstates'))
    ->with(compact('alltotals'))
    ->with(compact('merged'));
}
```

The outputs of this you can see on hennessey.io/map

Comment: At the moment I am struggling with updating the database with my form, so I wanted to get the other half of my project done and go back to it with a clearer mind. My goal with this is to eventually, once I assign these variables to the state acronym, run a loop which will assign different colors to different states depending on what number range they fit into.

Comment: have you tried `DB::table('distributors')->lists('state','total');` it will create an array for you and you don't have to use `array_combine`

Comment: I did do this, but I didnt know how to use it and make the $state equal to the number in $total using it.

Comment: I just created a third variable to be passed to the view from the controller, "merged' - 
  $merged = DB::table('distributors')->lists('state','total');
  return View::make('map')
  ->with(compact('merged'));
I will try and figure it out...

Comment: @user80648 What is $PA?

Comment: When I declared variables     @define $PA = ""... the value remains the same after the loop. Before I had it set to "0" and it remained "0".

Comment: I am having the same issue using the code I put below, following nathan's example

Comment: The way I suggested and the better way that mdamia suggested both work fine for me. Could you post your complete code for this? @user80648

Comment: You can see the outputs here: distributormap.hennessey.io/map

Comment: I will post the complete code in one second.

Comment: Using the answer I provided you would access `$PA` by doing $arr['PA'] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant modify the array that way using a foreach loop. The value is being assigned inside of the loop and being discarded after each iteration. You're [passing the key by value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Try doing it this way:

```
@define $arr = array_combine($allstates, $alltotals)
@foreach ($the_array as $key => $value)
    @define $arr[$key] = $value
@endforeach
```

This will modify the original array, rather than just the copy inside of the loop. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works?rq=1) some more information on how foreach loops work in PHP.

Comment: I am having difficulty using this and getting it to work. I can do the following and get the same output I had before, but $PA is still not defined as having a value of 15, which it actually does have in the database (and in the output I get using this:)

Comment: define $arr = array_combine($allstates, $alltotals)
    foreach ($arr as $allstates => $alltotals)
      define $array[$allstates] = $alltotals
      {{ $allstates }} {{ $alltotals }}
    endforeach